# how to list job ids from all users?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the Java API to query for all job ids using the code below

```
Bigquery.Jobs.List list = bigquery.jobs().list(projectId);
list.setAllUsers(true);
```

but it doesn't list me job ids that were run by Client ID for web applications (ie. metric insights) I'm using private key authentication.

Using the command line tool 'bq ls -j' in turn giving me only the metric insight job ids but not the ones ran with the private key auth. Is there a get all method?

The reason I'm doing this is trying to get better visibility into what queries are eating up our data usage. We have multiple sources of queries: metric insights, in house automation, some done manually, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hunch is that listing jobs for all users is broken, and nobody has mentioned it since there is usually a workaround. I'm currently investigating.

Comment: Yes -- this should work now. We haven't released the new version of bq that has "ls -j -a" support, but if you're using the java api as you show above, it should work to list all jobs for a project.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 2.0.10, the [bq client](http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/detail?r=0d5b4cd109ef6274fb695902ab59faed0ad23601) has support for API authorization using service account credentials. You can specify using a specific service account with the following flags:

```
bq --service_account your_service_account_here@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
    --service_account_credential_store my_credential_file  \
    --service_account_private_key_file mykey.p12 <your_commands, etc>
```

Type `bq --help` for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. What is the my_credential_file? I'm not sure where to get it. However, our main goal is insight into what's costing us. The info from the dashboard regarding usages is still too parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Jordan -- It sounds like you're honing in on what we want to do. For all access that we've allowed into our project/dataset we want to produce an aggregate/report of the "totalBytesProcessed" for all queries executed.

The problem we're struggling with is that we have a handful of distinct java programs accessing our data, a 3rd party service (metric insights) and 7-8 individual users who have query access via the web interface. Fortunately the incoming data only has one source so explaining the cost for that is simple. For queries though I am kinda blind at the moment (and it appears queries will be the bulk of the monthly bill).

It would be ideal if I can get the underyling data for this report with just one listing made with some single top level auth. With that I think from the timestamps and the actual SQL text I can attribute each query to a source.

One thing that might make this problem far easier is if there were more information in the job record (or some text adornment in the job_id for queries). I don't see that I can assign my own jobIDs on queries (perhaps I missed it?) and perhaps recording some source information in the job record would be possible? Just thinking out loud now...

Comment: You can assign your own job ids for queries. Just fill out the job id part of the job job reference when you create the query.

Comment: I'll take another look, didn't see that either in the java api or the plain bigquery api reference. I'm probably just blind (wouldn't be the first time). Of course this would only help us in some places, I don't suspect we can control the jobid of queries from our third party or those that originate from the web interface. Would still be great to list all queries from all sources and i'll infer from the sql where it came from

Comment: I couldn't find the API to set job Id for query job either (using java API). It would be great if the job status result contains the client id in it.

Answer (score 0):

There are three tables you can query for this.

`region-**.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_{USER, PROJECT, ORGANIZATION}`

Where `**` should be replaced by your region.

Example query for `JOBS_BY_USER` in the `eu` region:

```sql
select
  count(*) as num_queries,
  date(creation_time) as date,
  sum(total_bytes_processed) as total_bytes_processed,
  sum(total_slot_ms) as total_slot_ms_cost
from
 `region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER` as jobs_by_user,
 jobs_by_user.referenced_tables
group by
 2
order by 2 desc, total_bytes_processed desc;
```

Documentation is available at:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs